# jQuery removeClass to disable on('click',function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

as the title suggests, I have the following function:

```
$('.breadCrumb').on('click',function(){

    var bc = $(this).prop('id');
    var id = bc.split('_');
    $('#'+bc).removeClass("breadCrumb");
    //$('.'+bc).show();//show spinner on specific id
    $.ajax({
        url:'/ajax/breadcrumb/',
        data:{bc:id[1]}
    }).success(function(breadcrumb){
        $('#'+bc).html(breadcrumb);
        //$('.spinner').hide();
    });
});
```

The problem is, I am able to click again (for whatever reason) and I want to prevent someone from just clicking away and sending a query to the db every time, and

```
$('#'+bc).removeClass("breadCrumb");
```

is not working.   Can I get any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: $(this).removeClass("breadCrumb"); doesn't help

Comment: please mention you have multiple breadcrumbs, and u want to disable the clicked one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.breadCrumb').on('click',function(){
    $(this).off('click');
    var bc = $(this).prop('id');
    var id = bc.split('_');
    $('#'+bc).removeClass("breadCrumb");
    //$('.'+bc).show();//show spinner on specific id
    $.ajax({
        url:'/ajax/breadcrumb/',
        data:{bc:id[1]}
    }).success(function(breadcrumb){
        $('#'+bc).html(breadcrumb);
        //$('.spinner').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: That kind of worked but effectively disabled all other .breadCrumbs too! http://piecesparts.net/s/c142fcd1ae36f379  here is the site/page where the function needs to work

Answer (score 0):

Change `$('.breadCrumb').on('click',function(){` to `$('body').on('.breadCrumb', 'click',function(){`